# What does { .... } mean inside of a dword[ ... ]?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

In particular `edx, dword [ebp-0x10 {var_14}]`

I get that ebp-0x10 is ebp-16 but why is {var_14} included, which points to -14?

When I look in GDB at ebp-16 the thing I'm looking for is there but what's the relation to -14?

[image]

Comment: What disassembler is that from?  Also, it would be good to copy/paste as *text* at least the key parts of the output, like the frame_offset "declarations", and a few of the instruction's you're asking about.  Images of code are not accessible for blind users, or searchable.  If someone searched on `var_10 "{Frame offset -10}"`, they wouldn't currently find this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an annotation added by your disassembler to help you keep track of "named" variables.  Perhaps if there'd been debug symbols, you'd get names for them like `[ebp-0x10 {passcode}]`.

Treat it as a comment, because that's all it is.  The `[ebp - 0x10]` without the `{}` is a complete representation of the addressing mode.

(Plus you have the hex machine code which you could use to verify that disassembly.)

---

The `frame_offset - 14` annotation on the definition is in hex.  Note that there's one at `-2c`.  The return address is at "frame offset" `0` according to those same annotations, and the saved-EBP is at `-4`, because this is a traditional stack frame using EBP as a frame pointer.

Since that means EBP points at the saved EBP, the offsets from EBP differ by 4 from the `frame_offset` offsets.  Thus `frame_offset - 0x14` is `ebp - 0x10`.

Comment: Cheers, I was hoping that was the case